# How to make QtGui.QGraphicsScene additem() paint only the added item?

Tags: python, pyqt

If I have a chart with realtime data in a QGraphicsScene, each time I call addItem() to add a new portion of the plot, QGraphicsScene repaints all items, so over time adding new items is becoming slower and slower.

How can I prevent QGraphicsScene from painting all items, when I only need the one that was newly added to be painted?

I want all items to be painted when I e.g. resize the QGraphicsScene, just not when addItem() is called.

Comment: This sounds like a bad design to me. Probably you should not add items to the scene at all. You should draw your chart in a single item that holds the data internally OR at least break the chart items into a few logical groups ( like labels, lines, dots, guides and etc) and draw them in a few QGraphicsItem or QGraphicsWidget derived classes.

Comment: You should also ensure that you're not calling any `update()` function without actually needing it, and check the [`optimizationFlags()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#optimizationFlags-prop) and [`viewportUpdateMode()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#viewportUpdateMode-prop). Then, QGraphicsScene is capable of showing thousands of items without performance issues, the only bottleneck is if you you have complex processing done in python within painting operations (but not only), which is the point in which major optimization efforts must be done.

Comment: I suggest you to try to conceive a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that can consistently reproduce the actual issue, then edit your post to include it so that we can take a look and see if something can be done.

Comment: @mhrvth as already requested, please provide a MRE. Besides that, it's pretty normal that all the viewport gets updated at some point when the scene changes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As written in the comments, setting setViewportUpdateMode() with QGraphicsView::BoundingRectViewportUpdate AND not calling setUpdatesEnabled(True) solves the problem.

Comment: `updatesEnabled` is True by default for all widgets (including QGraphicsView). So, you either unset it somewhere in your code, or you're using an external class we don't know anything about that does that. In any case, both your question and your answer are not really useful to anybody, since from what you're describing your problem is not reproducible.

Comment: In fact, you're correct. setViewportUpdateMode() always worked correctly. But addItem() was being called in a loop and each time the QGraphicScene's updates were disabled with setUpdatesEnabled(False) after an item was added and enabled with setUpdatesEnabled(True) right before a new item was added,  which resulted in paint() being called on all items in every iteration, making it look like setViewportUpdateMode() has no effect.

Comment: If you add items in a loop within the same function, the view doesn't update each time on its own, as Qt is smart enough to *queue* updates; so, if you get the view updated each time an item is added then there's a problem in your implementation. Again, since we didn't know anything about this, the problem is not reproducible. I can understand that you didn't avoid to mention any of that by purpose, but that's one of the reasons for which a MRE is requested. If we don't know anything about your implementation, it's impossible for us to help you, and the question becomes pointless.